# Give users the ability to choose a location in order to save their file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, download

I am doing a spring MVC project and now I want to create a file path chooser.I am trying to give users the ability to choose a location in order to save their file. For eg, C:\testlocation\sublocation... I came across many posts that said it is impossible, as this could pose as a security threat. However, I am still curious to know if there is an alternative.

Comment: I don't understand; if the browser is asking you to save a file you have access to whatever directories on the client you'd *normally* have access to. What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're mixing two different functional requirements:

1. Being able to provide a file download with *Save As* dialog.
2. Being able to preset the default file location in *Save As* dialog so that the enduser doesn't need to browse the right folder first (e.g. "C:\foo\bar" instead of "C:\Users\John\Downloads").

The first is very easily possible by returning the whole file in HTTP response body along with this header:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"filename.ext\"");
```

The second is impossible as you figured based on the answers you found.